# How to make an element transparent to clicks but still visible?

Tags: html, css

I'm interested in putting an inset box shadow on something like an iframe. While the strategy of overlaying a div over the iframe gives the expected visual display, the div subsequently blocks clicks on the iframe itself.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/YqXPg/

So is there a way to pull off the inset shadow as a "framing" effect?

Comment: You may have to just create 4 elements - one for each border.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there's [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/YqXPg/3/

A version that makes the overlay more obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/YqXPg/4/

Note that this property doesn't work with IE, but if I remember correctly, IE will allow you to click through the transparent parts of the overlay `div` anyway.

Comment: +1, but sadly it doesn't work in IE (even the transparent version).

Comment: @Box9: I just tested it (the transparent version). You're right, it completely doesn't work with IE9. They've seemingly fixed the "bug" I described where you can click through it, which does work in IE8 (and IE9 in IE8 mode).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful solution. It's unfortunate that IE is uncooperative in this fashion, and it's a great shame that modernizr doesn't check for support for this.

Comment: IE8 allows the click-through, but IE6, 7, 9 and 10 do not.